Nested project variable not expanding in :variables block in GitLab
In GitLab, I have a project level variable in my upstream repo, lets say called ID = 29111. In the downstream repo, that variable also exists but it's value is 99999 I have another upstream project level variable that references ID like so REFERENCING_ID = $ID. Cool. I also have a job which triggers a downstream pipeline.
Upstream Job Triggering Downstream Pipeline
   variables:
     REFERENCING_ID = ${REFERENCING_ID}
   trigger: ...

My expectation is that the $ID will expand when being passed to the downstream pipeline and if I were to log REFERENCING_ID in the downstream pipeline I would get 29111. But I dont. When I log REFERENCING_ID in the downstream pipeline, I get 99999. When I make a call to the GitLab API to retrieve the pipeline variables for the downstream pipeline, REFERENCING_ID = ${ID}. It is not being expanded in the upstream. Because it is being passed as a variable ie ${ID}, it is using the downstream's ID
a "fix" is to also pass down ID to the downstream pipeline like so.
Upstream Job Triggering Downstream Pipeline
   variables:
     REFERENCING_ID = ${REFERENCING_ID}
     ID = ${ID}
   trigger: ... 

But that overrides the downstream ID, which I want to keep. What I want is that ID should have been expanded already in the upstream when being passed down to the downstream What am I missing here? Any help is massively appreciated.
